# Why does "neu" become "Neues" after "etwas"?

Tags: grammar, adjective

I found this sentence in a German children's book:

> Jeden Tag entdeckt Katrin etwas Neues.

Neues is a noun here?  How can that be?  I'd think that 'new' was an adjective.
As a noun, I found Neue in the dictionary, and then I found other cases of 'etwas Neues'

So what is happening here?  Is it, in fact, "Neue" that's been changed for some reason?

Answer (score 9):

There is a difference between the lexical part of speech and the functional. The lexical is kind of like the default part of speech while the functional is the actual usage. The lexical part of speech of "neu" is adjective. But it can have 3 funtions

> Das neu gekaufte Auto .. (neu - adverb)
>
> Das neue Auto.... (neu - adjective)
>
> Das Neue ... (Neue - noun)

The last use, the use as a noun, is something that German can do which English cannot. You can use any adjective as a noun if you want to. It then can take all three genders and come in all 4 cases. It stands for the prototypical entity of the respective gender plus the added characteristic of the adjective.

> Der Neue ist nett (the new guy/one)...
>
> Hast du der Neuen schon guten Tag gesagt? (the new woman)
>
> Ich nehme lieber das Neue (the new thing).

Comment: This answer doesn’t mention “Neues” at all. Seems like it should mention the “S” at the end.

Comment: What case is "der Neuen". Shouldn't it be den Neuen

Answer (score 5):

"Das Neue" is a noun. English translation : "Novel thing".

It is actually quite brilliant, as a lemma, since it perfectly fits for anything new or novel.

Of course it has the adjective "neu" at its root, similar to the nouns "Gutes", "Böses", "Altes" etc. (usw.) These mean "Good thing", "Old thing" and "Evil thing", respectively.

Comment: This was not about „das Neue“, but about „Neues“. And „Gutes“ or „Neues“ is more abstract than a good or new thing.

Comment: @Carsten I think you are splitting hairs, finely.

Comment: no he isn't......

Comment: He isn’t splitting hairs. The answer does not address the ending S. It should at least mention the ending s one time. It doesn’t.

Answer (score 3):

Words like `etwas`, `keine`, `viele` are called `Indefinitpronomen`.
There is a good explanation of the capitalisation in the context of Indefinitpronomen [on Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinitpronomen#Indefinitpronomen_im_Deutschen)

> Adjektive und Verben werden in diesem Fall substantiviert, z. B. etwas Großes, viel Neues, wenig Berauschendes, usw. Das gilt allerdings nur, wenn diese auch das Bezugswort darstellen, ansonsten fungieren sie als zusätzliche Attribute:
>
> - Es gab viel *Neues* zu bestaunen.
> - Es gab viele *neue* Dinge zu bestaunen

You can read more about those Indefinitpronomen in the linked/quoted article.

Comment: Interesting that „wenig Berauschendes“ can have two different meanings, one in which „wenig“ is an indefinite pronoun, the other in which it is an adverb.

Answer (score 2):

After the German orthography reform you're supposed to write every noun with a capital letter. It's always been that way, but there were some inconsistencies before (there still are some), so after this reform it was decided that adjectives made nouns were written with a capital letter.

Now, as to why this `Neues` is a noun. There are some words in German that turn an adjective into a noun. Among them is this little `etwas`. Here are some more:

> etwas, nichts, alles, jemand, usw.

You have to be careful, though, since these words have other functions and can stand alone in a sentence.

There are other ways of turning an adjective into a noun, of course; e.g.:

> Das ist eben das Blöde!

Note that `Blöde` is a noun in this case because of the `das` article.

Some sources:

[Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Gross-klein/Nominalisierung.html?lang=en)
http://odl.vwv.at/deutsch/odlres/res4/gk_RS2.htm

Comment: Also before the reform you were supposed to write every noun with a capital..because they're nouns. The point is what counts as a noun. Also, I do not need any of those little ords to turn an adjective a noun. I turn it a noun and then I can use these words, that how it is "Ich habe Gutes über dich gehört." no small words here.

Comment: @Emanuel Yes, the last part of my reply was an attempt at implying that this, of course, isn't the only way to turn adjectives into nouns, but I guess I did that poorly.

Answer (score 1):

> *Neues* is a noun here?

*Neues* is a **`substantiviertes Adjektiv`**

[This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=etwas%20%2a_NOUN&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2;,etwas%20%2a_NOUN;,c0;,s0;;etwas%20von_NOUN;,c0;;etwas%20Neues_NOUN;,c0;;etwas%20anderes_NOUN;,c0;;etwas%20Anderes_NOUN;,c0;;etwas%20Besonderes_NOUN;,c0;;etwas%20anders_NOUN;,c0;;etwas%20war_NOUN;,c0;;etwas%20Fremdes_NOUN;,c0;;etwas%20Bestimmtes_NOUN;,c0;;etwas%20hat_NOUN;,c0#t2;,etwas%20%2a_NOUN;,c0;,s0;;etwas%20von_NOUN;,c0;;etwas%20Neues_NOUN;,c0;;etwas%20anderes_NOUN;,c0;;etwas%20Anderes_NOUN;,c0;;etwas%20Besonderes_NOUN;,c0;;etwas%20anders_NOUN;,c0;;etwas%20war_NOUN;,c0;;etwas%20Fremdes_NOUN;,c0;;etwas%20Bestimmtes_NOUN;,c0;;etwas%20hat_NOUN;,c0) gives the following common ones

> etwas Neues
>   etwas Fremdes
>   etwas Anderes
>   etwas Bestimmtes

Also note that **sometimes you must not use caps** (see second stanza):

> Nun gibt es aber auch die Kombination aus **Präposition und flektiertem Adjektiv**, die ohne Artikel auskommt. Hierbei ist es Ihnen **freigestellt, das Adjektiv eher substantivisch zu sehen oder auch nicht**  vor kurzem ist genauso richtig wie vor Kurzem; seit längerem oder von neuem können Sie ebenso schreiben wie seit Längerem oder von Neuem. Falls Sie sich lieber feste Regeln merken: Die Dudenredaktion **empfiehlt** in diesen Fällen **die Großschreibung**.
>
> Der Vollständigkeit halber sei noch erwähnt, dass es auch **unflektierte Adjektive** bzw. Adverbien gibt, die **mit Präpositionen** verbunden auftauchen können. Hier gilt dann die **Kleinschreibung**: von nah und fern, von klein auf, in bar.
>   <sub>http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/substantivierungen-von-adjektiven</sub>